# Requisição ajax leva muito tempo para executar

Tags: php, ajax

Eu tenho uma requisição ajax em que o método usado é o POST, as informações que eu passo são com um objeto formData, nele tem algumas fotos que podem variar de 1 até 15, quando eu executo isso no localhost não dura 1 segundo, agora que subi o site para o servidor de hospedagem ele demora 120 e para de executar, a minha pergunta é, o que pode estar ocasionando isso visto que no servidor local executa quase instantaneamente?

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../controller/inserir_prova_banco.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(data){}
});
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Requisição php demorando 1 minuto quando executado no servidor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/273365/requisi%c3%a7%c3%a3o-php-demorando-1-minuto-quando-executado-no-servidor)

Answer (score -1):

Amigo, tem vários fatores que pode ocasionar isso.

Primeiro, o servidor local a latência é zero. Ele vai executar instantaneamente.

Agora quando é servidor web, em outro lugar.... ai sim, olha o que pode dar de problema para ficar tão lento.

1- Sua internet é extreamente leta e demora
2- Pode haver problema de rota, do seu computador até o servidor
3- O seu servidor web, pode estar sobre carregando com muitos clientes simultaneos....
4- Sua aplicação ta mal estruturada etc....

São varios fatores... mas o que eu acredito que seja, é que seu servidor está lento.... se não tiver POST de arquivos... acho que é seu servidor mesmo

Comment: Tu diz a estrutura e configuração do meu servidor de hospedagem? Se sim tem algo que eu possa pedir para eles mudarem? Eu acho que tem a ver com os arquivos, pois eu tenho outras requisições ajax que não passam arquivos como parâmetros, só texto, e então funciona.